# Lumen 8 - Using Faker in tests makes InvalidArgumentException: Unknown format "name"

Tags: testing, phpunit, lumen, faker

I'm using Lumen default Tests only added this line to the test :

`$users = \App\Models\User::factory()->count(5)->create();`

But i get this error when running the test :

`InvalidArgumentException: Unknown format "name"`

I did't touch the `UserFactory` Class i include it below , whats wrong with my code?

```
public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->name,
            'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncommented these lines in `app.php` and its working now :

```
$app->withFacades();

 $app->withEloquent();
```

Answer (score 2):

Should anybody else end up here looking for a similar issue in Laravel, make sure you include

```
parent::setUp();
```

in your setup method (if you have one). For example,

```
class ManageDocumentTest extends TestCase
{
    public $user;

    public function setUp():void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->user = User::factory()->create();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to extend use Tests\TestCase instead of PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.

At least, it helped me.

Comment: My problem was not related to this one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Tests\TestCase`, calling `parent::setUp();` and it still doesn't work, make sure not to call $faker before the actual test - ie. in a `@dataProvider` it won't work